# How can you slice with string keys instead of integers on a python OrderedDict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-internals, ordereddictionary

Since an `OrderedDict` has the features of both a list (with ordered elements), and a dictionary (with keys instead of indexes), it would seem natural that you could slice using keys.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> cities = OrderedDict((('san francisco', 650), ('new york', 212), ('shanghai', 8621), ('barcelona', 42423)))
>>> test['shanghai':]  # I want all the cities from shanghai to the end of the list
TypeError: unhashable type
```

What's interesting about this is that it's not the error you'd see due to `OrderedDictionary.__getslice__` not being implemented.  I tried adding my own `__getslice__` method to `OrderedDict`, but I keep running into this TypeError problem.  It seems like Python is doing some kind of type checking to enforce that slice keys are only integers, before they even get passed to the `__getslice__` function, how unpythonic!

```
>>> class BetterOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
        def __getslice__(self, start=None, end=None, step=1):
            return 'potato'

>>> test = BetterOrderedDict((('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4)))
>>> print test[1:4]
'potato'                           # ok this makes sense so far

>>> test['one':'four']
TypeError: unhashable type         # WTF, strings are hashable!
```

So my question is, why can't I implement non-int slices, what kind of type-checking is preventing the slice keys from even reaching my `__getslice__` function, and can I override it by implementing my `BetterOrderedDict` in C with bindings?

Comment: You want to create a slice from the key "one" until the key "four"?

Comment: Yup, because they have an order, it should be ok.

Comment: But... why? what's the purpose?

Comment: It's incredibly useful!  I'm adding a real world example to my question as an edit.  I have a list of cities that I'm iterating through, they need to be iterated through in order and not have duplicates.  Lets say my operation gets interrupted half way through and I want to resume where it stopped, I'd use `cities['lastcity':]`

Comment: Please see this PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/

Comment: @Asad put that in an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one, thanks for linking that! Also WOW, that was submitted in 2006!!

Comment: Note that in Python3.4, `slice('a','b')` works. `[1,2,3][slice('a','b')]` gives `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`

Comment: Another thing that might help you would be a BTree mapping that can yield not slices in the insertion order, but in actual alphabetical order. cities["chi": "nf"] could yield you the items from ["chicago", ..., "new york"]. It is a different construct than a dict, but there are a few 3rd party modules implementing this for Python

Comment: Why use a dict if you want it alpha sorted? Sort works just fine on strings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`__getslice__` is deprecated way of implementing slicing. Instead you should handle `slice` objects with `__getitem__`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class SlicableDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return 'potato({},{},{})'.format(key.start, key.stop, key.step)
        return super(SlicableDict, self).__getitem__(key)

>>> s = SlicableDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> s
SlicableDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)])
>>> s['a']
1
>>> s['a':'c']
'potato(a,c,None)'
```

And if you need more than potato, than you can implement all three slicing operations following way:

```
def _key_slice_to_index_slice(items, key_slice):
    try:
        if key_slice.start is None:
            start = None
        else:
            start = next(idx for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(items)
                         if key == key_slice.start)
        if key_slice.stop is None:
            stop = None
        else:
            stop = next(idx for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(items)
                        if key == key_slice.stop)
    except StopIteration:
        raise KeyError
    return slice(start, stop, key_slice.step)

class SlicableDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            items = self.items()
            index_slice = _key_slice_to_index_slice(items, key)
            return SlicableDict(items[index_slice])
        return super(SlicableDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            items = self.items()
            index_slice = _key_slice_to_index_slice(items, key)
            items[index_slice] = value.items()
            self.clear()
            self.update(items)
            return
        return super(SlicableDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            items = self.items()
            index_slice = _key_slice_to_index_slice(items, key)
            del items[index_slice]
            self.clear()
            self.update(items)
            return
        return super(SlicableDict, self).__delitem__(key)
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

This is the actual implementation of the slicing feature you are expecting.

`OrderedDict` internally maintains the order of the keys in the form of a doubly linked list. [Quoting the actual comment from Python 2.7.9](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Lib/collections.py#l33),

```
# The internal self.__map dict maps keys to links in a doubly linked list.
# The circular doubly linked list starts and ends with a sentinel element.
# The sentinel element never gets deleted (this simplifies the algorithm).
# Each link is stored as a list of length three:  [PREV, NEXT, KEY].
```

Now, to slice the dictionary, we need to iterate the doubly linked list, `__root`, which is actually a private variable, protected by the [name mangling mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

**Note:** This involves hacky name unmangling to use the `OrderedDict`'s internal data structures.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class SlicableDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            # Unmangle `__root` to access the doubly linked list
            root = getattr(self, "_OrderedDict__root")
            # By default, make `start` as the first element, `end` as the last
            start, end = root[1][2], root[0][2]
            start = key.start or start
            end = key.stop or end
            step = key.step or 1
            curr, result, begun, counter = root[1], [], False, 0

            # Begin iterating
            curr, result, begun = root[1], [], False
            while curr is not root:
                # If the end value is reached, `break` and `return`
                if curr[2] == end:
                    break
                # If starting value is matched, start appending to `result`
                if curr[2] == start:
                    begun = True
                if begun:
                    if counter % step == 0:
                        result.append((curr[2], self[curr[2]]))
                    counter += 1

                # Make the `curr` point to the next element
                curr = curr[1]

            return result

        return super(SlicableDict, self).__getitem__(key)
```

Few sample runs:

```
>>> s = SlicableDict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> s
SlicableDict([('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('e', 5), ('d', 4), ('f', 6)])
>>> s['a':'c']
[('a', 1)]
>>> s['a':]
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('e', 5), ('d', 4)]
>>> s[:'a']
[]
>>> s['a':'f':2]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)]
```

Comment: Great answer exposing the "plumbing" of `OrderedDict`s. I'd expect your answer to be much faster than mine, but be subject to breaking based on a change of implementation in `OrderedDict` (due to the name unmangling or etc), while the "porcelain" implementation I used is probably safe from breakage between versions but not nearly so fast as this.

Comment: Super thorough, thanks for actually implementing the functionality instead of potatoing it!  I looked at the OrderedDict implementation in the python source, but was missing the fact that I should use getitem instead of getslice.

Comment: @thefoureye What's with `getattr` instead of just `self._OrderedDict__root`?

Comment: This will also break when slicing on falsy items.

Comment: If you are depending on implementation details of `OrderedDict` anyway, why the linear search for the first element?  You could just as well use `self.__map` to jump there directly, and then do a linear serach for the last element.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (very ugly) implementation

```
class SliceOrdered(OrderedDict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            tmp = OrderedDict()
            i_self = iter(self)
            for k in i_self:
                if key.start <= k <= key.stop:
                    tmp[k] = self[k]
                    if key.step is not None and key.step > 1:
                        for _ in range(key.step-1):
                            try:
                                next(i_self)
                            except StopIteration:
                                break
            return tmp
        else:
            return super(SliceOrdered, self).__getitem__(key)
```

DEMO (Python3.4)

```
>>> s = SliceOrdered([('a',2), ('b',2), ('c',3), ('d',4)])
>>> s['a':'c']
OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> s['a':'d':2]
OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

***N.B.*** this probably only works because in this example, the `OrderedDict` was not only ordered, but also sorted. In an unsorted dictionary the slice `'a':'c'` does not necessary contain `'b'`, so my `if key.start <= k <= key.stop` logic probably fails. The following code should respect that:

```
class SliceOrdered(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, slice):
            return super(SliceOrdered,self).__getitem__(key)
        tmp = OrderedDict()
        step = key.step or 1
        accumulating = False
        i_self = iter(self)
        for k in i_self:
            if k == key.start:
                accumulating = True
            if accumulating:
                tmp[k] = self[k]
                for _ in range(step-1):
                    next(i_self)
            if k == key.stop:
                accumulating = False
                break
        return tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know \__getitem__ is used instead of getslice, this makes a lot of sense now.