# Iterate from one key to another in an OrderedDict

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have an `OrderedDict` in and I have two keys. I know that one key is stored before the other key and I would like to iterate all items between the first key to the second key.

I don't want to iterate over the whole map, because it's huge. Only the items between the two keys I have. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you slice with string keys instead of integers on a python OrderedDict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912308/how-can-you-slice-with-string-keys-instead-of-integers-on-a-python-ordereddict)

Comment: @Vishnudev: That iterates over the whole dict to find the keys.

Comment: Also, it only works on Python 2.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. Corresponding discussions about finding the index in an ordered dict require you to iterate over the dict at least once, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60841291/9501624

Answer (score -1):

You could use a pandas Series in place of the dict. pandas is a huge dependency though.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
>>> s = pd.Series(d)
>>> s['b':'d']
b    2
c    3
d    4
dtype: int64
>>> s['b':'d'].to_dict()
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

(Demo is with a regular dict because they are ordered with respect to key insertion since Python 3.7.)

Comment: This reads the whole dict to build the DataFrame. The goal of the question is to find a way to *not* iterate over the whole dict.